# Is there a way to get the beginning of a word based on the match of the end of the word?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that can find all words that end with "Ctrl" and get only the beginning of the word. So for "QuestionCtrl" I would only want to get "Question".

So far I've boiled it down to something like this: `\b(\w*(Ctrl)\w*)\b`

Comment: What is the programming language  / regex library?

Comment: `\b(\w+)Ctrl\b` would be it, taking $1.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for lookahead:

```
\b\w+(?=Ctrl\b)
```